# HP DL360 G8 - Configure ILO port as normal NIC remotely

Tags: networking, hp, ilo

I'm trying to configure the dedicated ILO mgmt port on a dl360 g8 server to be used as a regular NIC - the host is running one bare-metal machine (no esx). Can I configure this NIC as normal network in DHCP and then find the DHCP record to connect to it and give the machine it's fixed IP?

Note: this is an emergency situation after some incompetent engineer intervened on-site and pulled out all the cables from the non-ILO NIC's. This will be a work-around solution for the weekend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, it's not presented to the BIOS as a regular NIC.